# Slow performance when accessing msmdpump.dll with basic authentication

Tags: basic-authentication, ssas-2008

I enabled http access to my SSAS 2008 project. I am able to connect to
the project and the cubes via http:///olap/msmdpump.dll
I tried anonymous authentication and basic authentication. For
productive use I will have to use basic authentication.

In both settings I have quick access to the project and the cubes. But
it takes 10 times longer to draw the report with basic authentication.
Far too slow for the use in productive environment. After drawing the
report it is possible to navigate inside the cube (filter, drill) with
no performance problems.

In SQL Server profiler I compared both authentications. Con-string has
the same settings. It just takes 10 times longer to "Discover Begin >
Discover End" and in "Query Begin >> Query Subcube >> Query End".
NTUserName is the same in both variations as I put the same user for
the anonymous authentication.

I tried Windows Server 2003 and 2008. Same issue.
I tried to change several Con-settings

In both variations the server does not use proactive caching.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you ever managed to resolve this? The connection is unusable at the moment when using Basic Authentication.